# How to deal with Javascript that opens links in a popup window instead of a new tab?

Tags: firefox-extensions, popups

I absolutely don't want to have Firefox open a new window.

Is there an extension that could put the window back in the Firefox window as a tab ?

I have already activated an option that should prevent this (open new tab instead of a new window), but some people don't want their site to be correctly referenced and used tricks like this which circumvent this setting:

```
function popitup(id) {
    url="http://example.net/play.php?id="+id;
newwindow=window.open(url,'Video_Player','height=780,width=930');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
```

PS: This is not really a quality site, but here is where I found this: http://zomobo.net/stm32f4discovery. The function is in the file: `ajxfun.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [browser.link.open_newwindow](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow) to **3** and [browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction) to **2** under about:config or select the following option under `Tools menu / Options / Tabs`:

[image: 1]

However, as the browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction page states:

> This *[diverting all links]* does not include: JavaScript calls to window.open() with the "features" parameter (3rd parameter).

Thus since that page is using the 3rd param and specifying a height and width for the popup, it is allowed to break free and open a new window. (I don't understand the point of this BTW. If it is a user preference, then why leave this one loophole for obnoxious webmasters to inevitably exploit and thus irritate us?)

Anyway, the following add-ons might help.

1. [Tab Utilities](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/) has a single window mode that you can check out, among other "Force" options:

   [image: 2]
2. So does [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/):

   [image: 3]